# I copied word for word UIPopoverController code that worked for ipad on xcode 3.2 but it doesn't work on xcode 4.2

Tags: ios5, uipopovercontroller

I copied word for word UIPopoverController code that worked for ipad on xcode 3.2 but it doesn't work on xcode 4.2. Is there something wrong with popoverControllers for ipad or ios 5. It is the worlds simplest code: When a button is pressed I create a popoverController from a imagePicker and present the popoverContoller using presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem but it returns me to my main.m function and presents a breaker there.
Here is the link of the tutorial that I used:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gaaLMKuPwfU&feature=related

Comment: Here it is that helped me out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100510/crash-sigabrt-when-i-try-to-present-a-uipopovercontroller

Answer (score 1):

Set xib files property in Attribute inspector to relative to project By default it would be set to Relative to group.